# Ruby/Axlsx hiding a worksheet

Tags: excel, hide, axlsx

I was wondering i am using the [Axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) gem to generate excel documents from data in our system. I have several worksheets that use data validation and all the formulas are on a worksheet called lists. Is it possible to hide that worksheet so that people dont mess up the data validations?

I have looked through the [lib](http://rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Worksheet) and saw that you can hide *rows* or *columns* but nowhere about worksheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to hide a worksheet. You simply have to define its **:state** property:

```
  p  = Axlsx::Package.new
  wb = p.workbook

  # Worksheets in the :hidden state can be shown using the sheet formatting
  # properties in excel.
  wb.add_worksheet name: 'hidden', state: :hidden do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ['you cant see me!']
  end

  # :very_hidden sheets should be inaccessible to end users.
  wb.add_worksheet name: 'very hidden', state: :very_hidden do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ['you really cant see me!']
  end
```

**Sources:**

https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb

https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/worksheet.rb

Comment: Its not working for me, I have tried it in LibreOffice and google sheet as well.